# Cauchy Riemann Equation Complex Variable

Tags: complex-analysis

For any function $b=\ln[(x-1)^2 + (y - 1)^2 ]$ is harmonic and does not include the point $(1,2). $
Find a function $a$ such that $a + ib$ is analytic.
Express $a + ib$ as a function of $z.$

Comment: Hi and welcome to the site. Please learn LaTeX and MathJax typesetting. It will help getting good responses.

Comment: Maybe I do. But first you need to learn how to ask people in a way that makes them want to help you.

Comment: Hint: $b = \int b_y\,dy = \int a_x\,dy$.

Comment: @mathreadler Respected Sir you got me wrong. I apologize. I was just asking that do you know how to solve then please tell me.

Comment: No harm done in this case, but as a general rule of thumb it can be a good idea to ask the question in a more humble manner and also show any own attempts especially if it looks like it could be a homework question. Otherwise it is easy to attract both minus votes and candidacy for closure.

Comment: @mathreadler Thank you Sir for helping me. I have got the answer. Sorry to say but it's in one hand how to take one thing as positive or negative. I am being nice to you still but I didn't understand your above comment. I neither understand the thumb up thing. I will recommend everyone to take everything as a positive and don't show ego. Ego can ruin anyone. Thanks again. No hard feelings.

Answer (score 1):

Move the point $(1,1)$ (not $(1,2)$, as indicated) to $(0,0)$.Then we are given the harmonic function $$h(x,y):=\log(x^2+y^2)=2\log|z|\ ,$$
whereby $z:=x+iy$. Now we all know that $z\mapsto\log|z|$ is the real part of the analytic function
$${\rm Log}(z):=\log|z|+i\>{\rm Arg}(z)\ ,$$
which is defined in the complex plane with the negative real axis removed. The expression ${\rm Arg}(z)$ appearing here is the *principal value of the argument*, i.e., the polar angle $\phi$ of $z$ restricted to $-\pi<\phi<\pi$. It follows that a function $z\mapsto b(z)$ of the required kind is given by $b(z)=2\>{\rm Arg}(z)$. But there is no function $z\mapsto b(z)\in{\mathbb R}$ of the required kind that is defined in the full punctured plane $\dot{\mathbb C}$.